# Solving the limit $\lim_{n \to 0} \left[\frac{(2020+n)!}{2020!}\right]^{1/n}$

Tags: limits, contest-math

The title says it all! I have a solution for this limit, as I came up with this problem myself. However, I am planning on using this problem for students practicing for the Putnam, hence the $2020$ in the limit. I wanted to see what kind of solution methods might be used and also see if it is unrealistic to solve in a timely manner. So, my question is show me how you would solve 
$$\lim_{n \to 0} \left[\frac{(2020+n)!}{2020!}\right]^{1/n}$$
Note: It is unreasonable to find an exact answer; leave your answer in any numerical form you'd like. I think the final answer is quite "satisfactory" .

Comment: Rewrite using the gamma function, take logarithm, and apply L'Hospital's rule. I don't think that's a good Putnam practice problem since it's basically standard if you know the relevant functions. Putnam problems are usually more "creative."

Comment: @ParamanandSingh It is not. The result is $\exp(\psi(2020))$ and not $\exp(\psi(0))$, where $\psi(x)=\frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}$. Using the properties of $\psi$ one gets that the result is $\exp(H_{2020-1}-\gamma)$, where $H_n=1+1/2+...+1/n$  and $\gamma$ is Euler's constant.

Comment: @flan well, it's $\exp(\psi(2021))$.

Comment: OK i misinterpreted $n\to\infty $ instead of $n\to 0$ because of use of symbol $n$. Otherwise it's just $\exp(f'(2020))$ where $f(x) =\log\Gamma(1+x)$.

Comment: "Solving" is the wrong word. One _solves_ problems; one _solves_ equations. One _evaluates_ expressions.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the most general problem of $$\lim_{n \to 0} \left[\frac{(a+n)!}{a!}\right]^{\frac 1n}$$

$$y=\left[\frac{(a+n)!}{a!}\right]^{1/n}\implies \log(y)={\frac 1n}\log\left[\frac{(a+n)!}{a!}\right]$$ Now, using the expansion of
$$\log((a+n)!)=\log (a!)+n \psi ^{(0)}(a+1)+\frac{1}{2} n^2 \psi
   ^{(1)}(a+1)+O\left(n^3\right)$$
$$\log(y)=\psi ^{(0)}(a+1)+\frac{1}{2} n \psi ^{(1)}(a+1)+O\left(n^2\right)$$
$$y=e^{\log(y)}=e^{\psi ^{(0)}(a+1)}+\frac{1}{2} n e^{\psi ^{(0)}(a+1)} \psi
   ^{(1)}(a+1)+O\left(n^2\right)$$
Now, if $a$ is large
$$\psi ^{(0)}(a+1)=\log \left({a}\right)+\frac{1}{2 a}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$$
$$e^{\psi ^{(0)}(a+1)}=a+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{24 a}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$$
$$\psi ^{(1)}(a+1)=\frac{1}{a}-\frac{1}{2 a^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^3}\right)$$
$$e^{\psi ^{(1)}(a+1)}=1+\frac{1}{a}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^3}\right)$$
$$y=a+\frac{n+1}{2}+\frac{12n+1}{24a}+O\left(\frac{1}{a^2}\right)$$ which shows more than the limit.

Trying for $a=2020$ and a few values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 2021.000268 & 2021.000000 \\
 2 & 2021.500516 & 2021.499938 \\
 3 & 2022.000763 & 2021.999835 \\
 4 & 2022.501011 & 2022.499691 \\
 5 & 2023.001258 & 2022.999506 \\
 6 & 2023.501506 & 2023.499279 \\
 7 & 2024.001753 & 2023.999012 \\
 8 & 2024.502001 & 2024.498703 \\
 9 & 2025.002248 & 2024.998354 \\
 10 & 2025.502496 & 2025.497963 \\
 100 & 2070.524773 & 2070.298755
\end{array}
\right)$$